# Google Maps API imagePath local image not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have used [Google Maps Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) and its working as per my expectations.

Howerver I am facing one strange issue in `MarkerClusterer` - `imagePath` . When I set this..

`imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',`

Its working fine. However when I do this..

```
var imgpath = '<?= SITE_ROOT_IMAGE_DEFAULT ; ?>m3.png';


imagePath: imgpath,
```

And alerting it giving me my correct relative path, `/var/www/html/my-app/webroot/img/m3.png` where I have downloaded this image. But its not working.

I have also tried to add via `http`.

`imagePath: 'http://localhost/my-app/img/m3.png',`

I am able to see my image but its not working as well.

FYI , I have also downloaded my `markerclusterer.js` library in my local server and requesting it from my local only. And I am using [Cakephp 3.x folder structure](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html).

I have also tried with different ways like..

`imagePath: "../img/m",` But its not working either.

Can someone guide what I am doing wrong here ? Why my `imagePath` is not being taken ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading [the documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer), it says: *To use your own custom cluster images just name your images `m[1-5].png` or set the imagePath option to the location and name of your images like this: `imagePath: 'customImages/cat'` for images `cat1.png` to `cat5.png`.*

You should use a **relative path** to the file where you declare this path.

Here is an example folder structure:

```
- cluster_images
    - m1.png
    - m2.png
    - m3.png
    - m4.png
    - m5.png
- main.js
```

If you declare `imagePath` in the file `main.js` with the above folder structure, then it should be:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'cluster_images/m'});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to **style** each image separately and define your images sizes then you should use the `styles` parameter and declare each cluster icon separately.

```
mcOptions = {
  styles: [{
      height: 53,
      url: "https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m1.png",
      width: 53
    },
    {
      height: 56,
      url: "https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m2.png",
      width: 56
    },
    {
      height: 66,
      url: "https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m3.png",
      width: 66
    },
    {
      height: 78,
      url: "https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m4.png",
      width: 78
    },
    {
      height: 90,
      url: "https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m5.png",
      width: 90
    }
  ]
}

//init clusterer with your options
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

The above code uses the default images. Replace the URLs again with the **relative path** to each image and update the sizes to avoid image stretching.

Comment: When I use your default images code, I get broken images displayed on the Google map, even though the links you provided (e.g. https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images/m5.png) are linked to valid images, what's happening?

Comment: No idea. Open a question, include a [mcve] and provide debugging details.